# Flame changeing water temp faster when boiling as opposed to heating it up

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, field-theory, water

Cooking beans I noticed that, after the beans came to a boil, they reacted much more quickly to the turn of the dial than cold. I'm wondering if the water an everything else is more sensitive and quicker acting to temperature changes when hot? Does temperature make things, actions, travel faster? Like, the thicker something is, the slower things more through it. Is it the hotter something is the faster things move through it? Like the heat from the flame? That is what seemed to happen. Can temperature move faster through heat than through cold? Can things move faster through heat than through cold? That seems obvious to me there, but I wanted to throw it in.

Comment: What do you describe with "they reacted much more quickly" what reaction do you mean?If water boils it keeps it's temperature so it can not change it quicker, if you add more heat to boiling water you have more bubbles and so more movements of anything in the water

Comment: While the quation is veruy poorly phrased, the observed effect is probably due to the lower *specific heat capacity* of the beans, compared to 'pure' water.

Comment: trula - It bubbles slower then faster when I increase the flame or decrerase the flame very fast when its hot not when its cold.

Comment: when it is cold it should not bubble? bubbles are creating from boiling , its mostly vapor bubbles. i don't understand  " It bubbles slower then faster when I increase the flame " please describe exactly what you observe , what do the beans m what the bubbles?

Comment: What he is asking: When water is boiling and you increase or decrease the flame, you see an immediate change to how vigorously it boils. You do not see an immediate change when the water is cold. Why is this?

Comment: Thank you mmesser314 you are the closest to understanding me. I see heat as a wave. Heat against cool water does not pass through the water well (slow). Heat against hot water passes through it well and quick. Your thought helped me organize mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once water reaches around 100 degrees Celsius, varying slightly with altitude, it cannot remain liquid. It will then begin boiling and turn to steam. Once it is boiling increasing the heat of the stove will increase the steam bubbles quickly as the liquid water cannot get hotter, so the added heat goes to producing more steam bubbles. When the liquid water is well below 100 degrees increasing the stove's heat will increase the water temperature which will not show noticeable visible changes until it reaches boiling temperature.

Comment: It can remain a liquid at 100 C, standard pressure, if you stop putting energy into it.

Comment: This answer really doesn't address the question, IMO.